React Prompt is not getting rendered, when trying to switch to new location in router
This is my code for react custom prompt, please help to clearify the mistake. here I'm trying to render this when we switch to a different route. but everytime when i switch to different route it doesn't render. it render only when i click on the same nav link in navbar
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Prompt, useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Box, Modal, Typography, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import ModalWrapper from "./modal-container";

export function ReactPrompt(props: {
  content: string;
  title: string;
  isBlocked: boolean;
}) {
  const { content, title, isBlocked } = props;
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState<any>(location);
  const [shouldUnload, setShouldUnload] = useState(false);
  const [confirmedNavigation, setConfirmedNavigation] = useState(false);

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
    setShouldUnload(false);
  };

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
    console.log(isBlocked, isModalOpen)
  };

  const showModal = (nextLocation: string) => {
    console.log(nextLocation, isBlocked, isModalOpen)
    openModal();
    setLastLocation(nextLocation);
  };

  const handleBlockedRoute = (nextLocation: string): boolean => {
    
    if (!confirmedNavigation && isBlocked) {
      showModal(nextLocation);
      console.log(nextLocation, isBlocked, isModalOpen)
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  const handleConfirmNavigationClick = () => {
    closeModal();
    setConfirmedNavigation(true);
  };

  // Block react routes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (confirmedNavigation && lastLocation) {
      // Navigate to the previous blocked location with your navigate function
      setShouldUnload(true);
      history.push(lastLocation.pathname);
    }
  }, [confirmedNavigation, lastLocation, history]);

  // Block non-react routes
  useEffect(() => {
    const unload = (event: { returnValue: string }) => {
      if (isBlocked && !shouldUnload) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        event.returnValue = content;
      }
      if (shouldUnload) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        event.returnValue = "";
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unload);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unload);
  }, [isBlocked, content, shouldUnload]);

  console.log(isModalOpen)
  return (
    <>
    <Prompt when message={handleBlockedRoute} />
    {isModalOpen && (<ModalWrapper open = {isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
      <Box>
        <h1>{content}</h1>
        <Button size="large" color="primary" variant="outlined" onClick={closeModal}>
          Discard Changes
        </Button>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleConfirmNavigationClick}>
          save
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </ModalWrapper>)}
    </>
  );
}


I want rendering this in my component like this, what could be the issue with this?
 <ReactPrompt content="You have unsaved changes on this page." isBlocked ={isDirty}></ReactPrompt>


